# Appending to GCD Queue

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I was wondering if its possible to "append" something to an existing queue.. For example, let's say I take 15 photos and I want to process them sequentially, how can I append a photo to the queue?

I currently use something like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t photoProcessingQueue; // Declared as IVAR

photoProcessingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("PROCESSING_QUEUE", NULL); // in ViewDidLoad

dispatch_async(photoProcessingQueue, ^{ // in Processing Method
   Processing photos..
});
```

So I guess my question is, if the queue is in the middle of processing a photo, what happens when I call it again? Does it just wait until the first process is done before processing the next one by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you've created a concurrent queue.  This means that if you enqueue multiple blocks, they are executed in parallel, up to some up limit that the system determines based on available resources.  If you enqueue another block, it will be executed as soon as there is a free thread to run it.

Comment: Okay, so hypothetically speaking, if I call the "processing method" 5 times, it'll be executed sequentially? No matter if the queue is already processing when I call it?

Comment: No.  The submitted blocks will be executed in parallel, because you created a concurrent queue.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense.. Is it possible to create a concurrent queue that executes the methods in the sequence that they were passed in? If so, what is the definition of such thread?

Comment: That's a contradiction in terms.  Concurrent means "at the same time".  Create a serial queue if you want ordered operations.